# Location Updates on Boot - turn on and off in activity

Tags: android, location

I started with Googles [LocationUpdatesPendingIntent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesPendingIntent) example.
I've moved the location stuff from the Main Activity to the onBoot broadcast receiver as I need location updates to start straight away when the device boots. This works perfectly and provides a notification in the status bar.

But how do I go about turning the location updates on and off from an Activity?

This is for polling vehicle locations.

This is my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class StartupComplete1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // Every 10 seconds.
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000; // Every 5 seconds
private static final long MAX_WAIT_TIME = UPDATE_INTERVAL * 2; // Every 20 seconds.
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        createLocationRequest();

        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, getPendingIntent(context));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error - Cant start location updates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATES);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great idea to start checking for location updates in broadcast receiver. Based on android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for broadcast receiver

> As a general rule, broadcast receivers are allowed to run for up to 10 seconds before they system will consider them non-responsive and ANR the app. Since these usually execute on the app's main thread, they are already bound by the ~5 second time limit of various operations that can happen there (not to mention just avoiding UI jank), so the receive limit is generally not of concern. However, once you use goAsync, though able to be off the main thread, the broadcast execution limit still applies, and that includes the time spent between calling this method and ultimately PendingResult.finish().

This could cause ANR when location updates takes longer time for responding, especially if you are indoors.

You should start a sticky service on Boot completed broadcast receiver's onReceive(). MainActivity can then bind to this service to perform the necessary action.

This approach could have issues if you are targeting Android O. Please check [this post](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) which explains background location gathering on Android O.

Comment: Thanks. So I put all my location logic in a class and start it like so from the broadcast receiver?    Intent serviceIntentLocation = new Intent(context, LocationHelper.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntentLocation);

Comment: Yes. Your LocationHelper should extend Service. You can follow [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)  to bind service to your activity